# For $p\geq0$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdots n^{n^p})^{1/n^{p+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}}=e^{\frac{-1}{(p+1)^2}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Question: For real number $p\geq0$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdots n^{n^p})^{1/n^{p+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}}=e^{\frac{-1}{(p+1)^2}}$ **using Lagrange's Mean Value Theorem**.

I am aware of the following method:

> Let $\alpha=\frac{(1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdots n^{n^p})^{1/n^{p+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}}$, Now taking $\ln$ on both the sides we get $\ln\alpha=\ln\frac{(1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdots n^{n^p})^{1/n^{p+1}}}{n^{\frac{1}{p+1}}}$. Simplifying this we get $\ln\alpha=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{k}{n})^{p}\ln k-\frac{1}{p+1}\ln n$. Now adding and subtracting $\ln n$ in the very first expression  inside sum we get $\ln\alpha=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}[(\frac{k}{n})^p\ln \frac{k}{n}+(\frac{k}{n})^p\ln n]-\frac{1}{p+1}\ln n$. Using The Reimann Sum we will get $ \alpha=\exp(-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2})$.

I am having trouble in making the choice of such function ( moreover, motivation behind its construction too). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(1^{1^p}2^{2^p}\cdots n^{n^p})^{1/n^{p+1}}}{n^{1/(p+1)}
}.$$
$$\implies \ln L=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \ln k^{k^p}-\frac{\ln n}{p+1}.$$
$$\implies \ln L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n^{p+1}}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^p \ln k-k^p\ln n+k^p\ln n\right)-\frac{\ln n}{p+1}$$
$$\implies \ln L=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^p \ln \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\right)+\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k^p}{n^{p+1}}\ln n-\frac{\ln n}{p+1}$$
Now we use $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p \sim \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}.....(*)$$
$$\ln L=\int_{0}^{1} x^p \ln x dx=-\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-(p+1)t} dt=-\frac{1}{(p+1)^2}.$$
$$\implies L=e^{-1/(p+1)^2}.$$

**Edit** Let me also prove(*) below:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k^p}{n^p}=\int_{0}^{1} x^p dx=\frac{1}{p+1}.$$
Therefore for $n\sim \infty$, we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^p \sim \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}$$

Comment: Thanks for paying heed to the question but I am looking for a solution making the use of LMVT (have mentioned it above) .

Comment: Sorry I missed your point but I am yet to see an example of finding limit using LMVT!  Any example!

Comment: I am referring to http://facultymembers.sbu.ac.ir/shahrokhi/ProBookMathAnal2.pdf. Please visit page-9, mentioned under Independent Study. The function is mentioned there, but I am unable to understand the motivation behind its constructions.

Comment: I  do not.have access to it.

Comment: Try this http://users.uoa.gr/~dcheliotis/Andreescu%20T.%20Problems%20in%20Real%20Analysis%20-%20Advanced%20Calculus%20on%20the%20Real%20Axis%20(Springer%202009).pdf

Comment: You can't say that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k^p}{n^{p+1}} \ln n - \frac{\ln n}{p+1} \right)= 0$$ from $\sum_{k=1}^n k^p \sim \frac{n^{p+1}}{p+1}$ alone, so this answer is incomplete.

Comment: @ZAhmed: does [this link](https://facultymembers.sbu.ac.ir/shahrokhi/ProBookMathAnal2.pdf) work better?

Comment: Thanks @robjohn, please tell the page no. there.

Comment: I assume that the part cited is at the bottom of page 9.

Comment: Thanks @robjohn I will try it out.  I would love to see and answer from you.

Comment: I wrote an answer, but it is not much different than the approaches already given; it just has more details filled in.